# How to make iFrame not have the scrolling bar

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am working on making a widget like this one here:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?hike_id=176&height=400&width=700

And for some reason I can't seem to make scrolling bar go away.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [HTML iframe scrolling Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like this:

```
<iframe ... scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

**Edit:** Also `frameborder="0"` is handy to hide the border.

Comment: The OP didn't specify a standard, but the `frameborder` and `scrolling` attributes are not valid HTML 5.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Answer (score 5):

The CSS property that deals with the document being larger than the **viewable area** is `overflow`.

This is commonly used to make scrollable `div`s as seen in [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

The value you're looking for is: `hidden` which will **clip the area** outside of the visible range. Something like:

```
<iframe style="overflow:hidden;" src="URL" />
```

Should look nice a a widget

So for CSS properties you might want:

```
overflow:hidden;
border:none;
width:100px;
height:25px;"
```

And for iframe properties you probably want:

```
scrolling="no"
frameborder="0"
allowTransparency="true"
```

**Read up** on these to **understand** what they do, but they are the ones **common to widgets** like what you describe in your question. Together they should produce a good looking widget.

Answer (score 3):

```
iframe { overflow: hidden; }
```

ought to do it. However, do you *really* want to do that? Any content that is not immediately viewable will then not be available (without the user jumping through hoops to scroll it via the keyboard).

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` is inconsistent across browsers.  For me it works great on Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE :(

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `scrolling="no"` attribute to your iframe.

> Note: this will not work in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Although

`overflow:hidden;`

may work with Firefox, it doesn't work with IE or Chrome. If you are NOT using HTML5, then you can use `scrollable=no`.